# Create QueryBuilder

Tags: php, query-builder

Good morning folks,

Say I have a class:

`$query = new QueryBuilder();`

With all all "cute" methods

`$query->select(bla, bla, bla)->from(bla)->where(bla, bla, bla)`

But there is a part that needs to receive the return of SubQuery:

`$query->in(function($subquery) {});`

I'm just not able to implement this function to receive the return of SubQuery.

I am developing the class to my framework, but I'm just picking up a bit for the return of the subquery.

Grateful.

Comment: Well my guess would have been that: (1) Your query builder will eventually return a string representing the query i.e. `$queryBuilderObject->buildQuery() -> "Select bla bla bla"`. (2) The `IN` clause will enclose the result of another `QueryBuilder` in parentheses (i.e. `SELECT * FROM a WHERE b IN (".$invokeFunctionWhichReturnsQueryBuilder()->buildQuery().")`

Comment: Yes ... it returns a string, but I'm picking to create the callback method. If the IN clause, returns in parenthesis ... this part solve quiet because it can be IN, can WHERE etc.

Comment: You should look into the eloquent query builder as it actually does this already so unless you are required to make your own, don't reinvent the wheel. And do provide some code of what you've already tried. A minimal example which outlines your problem.